# Export CDK Generated InternetGateway Resource [AWS Cloudformation]

Tags: amazon-web-services, stack, export, aws-cloudformation, aws-cdk

So I have a basic VPC setup on CDK, after running `cdk synth` I see that an `AWS::EC2::InternetGateway` construct has been generated in my template under cdk.out. The problem is that I need to export this resource to another stack, but I can't reference `this.vpc.internetGatewayId` in my main .ts cdk file to export.

I know that this resource has been created, so I won't use `CfnInternetGateway` to create another, but at the same time `this.vpc.internetGatewayId` seems to have returned undefined even though I have a public subnet created and the resulting resource is in the template file.

Below is my VPC construct:

```js
    this.vpc = new ec2.Vpc(this, 'VPC', {
            cidr: CONFIG.REGIONAL_CONFIG[region].VPC_CIDR,
            maxAzs: CONFIG.REGIONAL_CONFIG[region].AVAILABILITY_ZONES,
            subnetConfiguration: [
                {
                    name: 'public',
                    subnetType: ec2.SubnetType.PUBLIC,
                },
                {
                    name: 'private',
                    subnetType: ec2.SubnetType.PRIVATE_WITH_NAT,
                },
                {
                    name: 'isolated',
                    subnetType: ec2.SubnetType.PRIVATE_ISOLATED,
                },
            ],
        });
```

Comment: "export the resource to another stack" ... in the same CDK app?

Comment: Hi, thanks for answering! I realized I should of clarified more in that I need to have the construct exported under the “Outputs” section, not just under “Resources” in the template.json file. This is because I need to import the construct in another separate stack (in the same AWS region).

Comment: Is the VPC-importing stack defined in the \*same CDK app\* as the VPC-exporting stack?

Comment: The VPC importing stack is not defined in the same CDK app as the exporting stack; the only similarity they have is that they are both in the same aws region. So far I've only been able to import constructs through exportValue:  `this.exportValue(this.vpc.vpcId)` which creates the Export name under the "Outputs" section of the template file; however I can't do this with `InternetGatewayId`. Hope that clears it up!

Answer (score 0):

Create a CloudFormation output on the exporting stack with with a [CfnOutput](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.CfnOutput.html):

```js
// MyExportingStack.ts

// Cause the synth to fail if the ID is undefined.  Alternatively, throw an error.
if (!vpc.internetGatewayId)
    cdk.Annotations.of(this).addError('An Internet Gateway ID is required!');

// Create the CloudFormation Output
new cdk.CfnOutput(this, 'IgwId', { value: vpc.internetGatewayId ?? 'MISSING', exportName: 'my-igw-id',});
```